# NavigationBar title is coming in black color

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I am using a `UINavigationBar` in my app with `UITabBar`.
On the first tab, the navigation bar title is coming properly as a white title with the default background color, but on the second tab it's not working in the same way. I'm not using any code to change the title color or the navigation bar's `tintColor`.

First view:
http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/7192/4go.png

Second View:
[image]

Why is the second view's `UINavigationBar` title drawn in this black color?

Comment: i think you should set color to navigation bar  tittle in second view check out that

Answer (score 26):

Generally, you can not change default color of `UINavigationBar` Title. In case of If you want to change color of UINavigationBar Title than you need to customize  UINavigationBar. so put code for your second ViewController for more Understanding.

**EDIT:**

After searching, I found that You can change title color of `UINavigationBar` by

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
```

This code is working in **iOS5 and later.**

Comment: I tried to change the color of title but it's not working. One more thing second view controller code is not affecting if I am using new viewController without any code, same problem is occurring.....

Comment: @rivan if you working on iOS 5 then put this code in ViewDidLoad Method I tried it on my project it working for me :)

Comment: Isn't the question about why the text is already changing colour, not how to customise it?

Comment: @JamesP Yaa, It's not about how to change navigation bar title color.

Comment: For iOS7 you will have to change UITextAttributeTextColor to NSForegroundColorAttributeName

Answer (score 10):

Most of the above suggestions are deprecated now, for iOS 7 use -

```
NSDictionary *textAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                               [UIColor whiteColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName, 
                               [UIColor whiteColor],NSBackgroundColorAttributeName,nil];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes;
self.title = @"Title of the Page";
```

Also, checkout the NSAttributedString.h for various text properties that could be set.

Comment: This worked great for me. I was about to post this for an updated iO7 fix, gave the up vote!

Answer (score 8):

Try this in AppDelegate:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

Comment: Thanks. That's the correct answer. You want to set this in appearance as in a normal app you really kind of want all the navigation bars to look the same.

Answer (score 7):

This will allow you to change the colors

```
NSDictionary *navbarTitleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [UIColor whiteColor],UITextAttributeTextColor, 
                                        [UIColor blackColor],      UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
                                        [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(-1, 0)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, nil];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:navbarTitleTextAttributes];
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this bit of code for iOS7 as `UITextAttributeTextColor` has been deprecated.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor orangeColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
```

Answer (score 1):

This code changes the text of all the navigationBar, with this code the text can be customized 100%.

in appDelegate:

```
 //custom text navBar
   [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: 
   [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor colorWithRed:0x73/255.0 green:0x47/255.0 blue:0x41/255.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextColor,
   [UIColor colorWithRed:0x1D/255.0 green:0x1D/255.0 blue:0x1B/255.0 alpha:1], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
   [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)],UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, 
   [UIFont fontWithName:@"yourFont" size:20], UITextAttributeFont, nil]];
```

Comment: when I am using your code it's changing firstview navigationController title in black color and all the view that are under firstNavigation(after push view) are in white color.